# Pivoting for rows as columns - rating database

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I have the following tables:

RATINGS

```
User-ID     ISBN    Book-Rating
244662  0373630689  3
19378   0812515595  2
238625  0441892604  5
180315  0140439072  1
242471  3548248950  1
```

`BOOKS
ISBN        Book-Title      Book-Author   Year-Of-Publication   Publisher
0393000753  A Reckoning     May Sarton    1981                  W W Norton`

Using MySQL, I want to create a table that looks like this:

`----- User1    User2     User3  ...
ISBN1  Rating11 NaN       Nan
ISBN2  NaN      Rating21  Rating23
ISBN3  Rating31 NaN       NaN
...`

I've learned how to do it for a fixed number of columns [here](http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/). But how to convert the rows into columns? I have tried something like

`create view BX-Book-Ratings-Extended as (
  select`
ISBN`,
    case when`Book-Rating`= "1" then 1 end as`User-ID`,
    case when`Book-Rating`= "2" then 2 end as`User-ID`,
    case when`Book-Rating`= "3" then 3 end as`User-ID`,
    case when`Book-Rating`= "4" then 4 end as`User-ID`,
    case when`Book-Rating`= "5" then 5 end as`User-ID
  `from`BX-Book-Ratings
`)`

which doesn't work - the view is empty... I also tried to adopt a solution from [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns?rq=1) thread, but keep getting a syntax error I can't identify:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'ifnull(SUM(case when `Book-Rating` = ''',
      `User-ID`,
      ''' then `Book-Rating` end),0) AS ',
      `User-ID`
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  `BX-Book-Ratings`;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ISBN, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM BX-Book-Ratings 
                   GROUP BY ISBN');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The dataset is [here](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Ecziegler/BX/).

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Strawberry In order to train a recommendation system.

Comment: It seems unlikely that such a system would be built inside MySQL

Comment: @Strawberry I need a database to store the data. Why not MySQL?

Comment: How many unique users do you have? This could be quite the query.

Comment: You need a database to store the data. But the recommendation system is (presumably) a bunch of algorithms and some kind of friendly interface - so not a database as such.

Comment: @Strawberry I am not following you. The OP said they have two tables in a MySQL database... Ratings (with UserID) and Books... and they want to pivot the ratings for each user.

Comment: @JacobH 105 000 unique users who ever rated and 136 000 books (after grouping by title and author, about twice ISBNs). So yes, it is a few tens of GB uncompressed.

Comment: @JacobH Yes - but I think the OP is confused about what a database is for - which parts of a given problem it's sensible for a database to solve

Comment: Well now that we know there would be 105,000 columns in the pivot I do agree that a pivot seems... unwieldy. I don't even know if MySQL can handle that (I'm SQL Server mostly). A plain old SELECT with a JOIN should suffice I think, as long as OP is OK with multiple rows per user.

Comment: @Strawberry I don't understand what your objections are. Should I not store the data in a database? Should I not use SQL for pivoting?

Comment: @JacobH I agree. But a collaborative filtering algos need this format. Do you know of a better approach?

Comment: You should store the data in the database. You should not use sql for pivoting

Comment: @Strawberry But you still agree with using pivot? So building the table row-wise from another script?

Comment: Well I don't agree with it. But you indicated that it was something you wanted. So, processing a normal result set in application code, so as to output in whatever manner best suits your requirements.

Comment: And how will you display the ultra-wide line??

Comment: @RickJames What line do you mean? I don't need to display the table...

Comment: Then why put them in columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second attempt with dynamic SQL (prepare/execute) was close.
Try this query:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT Concat(
         'SELECT ISBN, ',
         Group_Concat( x SEPARATOR ','),
         ' FROM ratings GROUP BY ISBN '
       )
INTO @sql
FROM (
  SELECT Concat('Max( CASE WHEN User_ID = ', 
                User_ID, 
               ' THEN Book_Rating END ) As User_', 
               User_ID 
         ) As x
  FROM ratings 
  GROUP BY User_ID
  ORDER BY User_ID
) x;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/GLJV4738

If one user can have more ratings for one book, then replace `max` with `sum`.

---

Unfortunately this solution is not supposed to work for more than a copule of thousand of users (columns) due to [MySql limits](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limits.html)

- MySQL has hard limit of 4096 columns per table (so the query resultset cannot have more than 4096 columns too)
- MySQL table has a maximum row size limit of 65,535 bytes (more on this [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html)), so 150.000 users in a row must for sure have more than 65 k bytes